# How can i rewirite this kind of form into SDP standard form

Tags: convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

While i was reading the article, which can be viewed at [article](https://projet.liris.cnrs.fr/imagine/pub/proceedings/ICPR-2012/media/files/0209.pdf). the writer says that  (2) formula is a typical Semidefinite problem. but how can I transform it into the standard form so that I can solve it by some software package?

the form is：
$$\underset{M,s}{\text{min}} \quad -s\\
subject\;{to}\quad Tr(D_{ij}M)\geq{s}\quad 1\leq{i}<j\leq{c}\\
Tr(M)=1\\
0\preceq{M}\preceq{I}
$$

By the way, what if $M=ww^T$ where $w$'s elements are all positive, which means $w\succeq{0}$. then how I should add this into the SDP formed constraint

Comment: Is $s$ a scalar? Is it necessarily non-negative?

Comment: yes,$s$ is a scalar

Comment: The trick is to take your PSD matrix to represent
$$
\pmatrix{M\\ & I - M\\ && s}.
$$
The zero entries off of the block-diagonal are enforced by trace constraints, as is the relationship between the first and second diagonal block.

Comment: THX Ben, one more thing, just plz check my added new question, any idea?

Comment: The rank one constraint $M=ww^{T}$ is a non-convex constraint that can't be represented by SDP.